# DataGridview I tried an if-else-condition in DataGridView cells

Tags: if-statement

DataGridView

I tried an if-else-condition in DataGridView cells

```
Dim RowIdx As Integer
RowIdx = dgAttendance.CurrentRow.Index
If dgAttendance.Item(3, RowIdx).Value = "P" Or dgAttendance.Item(3, 
RowIdx).Value = "P " Then
   dgAttendance.Item(3, RowIdx).Value = "A"
EndIF
```

Please give the solution in C#. How do i use that if-else-statement in C#

Comment: Please show us what have you tried and what are your actual issues getting the problem solved. Also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How Do I try That Code In C#....

Comment: Learn the basics, e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/getting-started/). When you are done you will know how to do this.

Comment: i Tried This:      int index = dg_attendance.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            if (dg_attendance.CurrentRow.Index.ToString() == "P")
            {
                dg_attendance.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() = "A";

        }

Comment: Only Convert The Code From VB To C#

Comment: The code you tried should be edited into your question, not in a comment - however, I added an answer based on your code. Please try if it helps and mark it as answer if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you provided in your comments - you should not call .ToString() when setting your value as this removes the reference to your cell and returns an independent value. Try this instead:

```
dg_attendance.CurrentCell.Value = "A";
```

You also probably want to access the value of the third cell in your row by something like this:

```
dg_attendance.CurrentRow[3].Value
```